# How do I check answers in array objects by its index?

Tags: javascript, object, indexing

I am trying to build a quiz in JavaScript. I have an object with a question, answers and the correct answer. I can check whether the user has answered the question correctly by matching the index from the answers to the index of the correct answer.

However, when I try to use multiple objects and try to run this code, it doesn't work. How can I make this work?`

this works:

```
let questions = {
  question: "How many sides does a square have?",
  answers: [4, 6, 8],
  correctAnswer: 0,
  category: "trueOrFalse"
};

const iterator = questions.answers.keys();
for (const key of iterator) {
  if (key === questions.correctAnswer) {
    console.log(questions.question + ": " + questions.answers[key]);
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work:

```
let questions =
  {
    question: "How many sides does a square have?",
    answers: [4, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },
  {
    question: "How many sides does a triangle have?",
    answers: [3, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }
;

const iterator = questions.answers.keys();
for (const key of iterator) {
  if (key === questions.correctAnswer) {
    console.log(questions.question + ": " + questions.answers[key]);
  }
}
```

Here is the link to my repo: [DC Quiz](https://github.com/mvdgragt/DC-Quiz)

The problem occurs when I try to answer question 4. In my code you can see it is faulty in the main.js file on row 206.

Thank you for any help!
Michiel

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your questions as an array of objects.

```
let questions = [
  {
    question: "How many sides does a square have?",
    answers: [4, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },
  {
    question: "How many sides does a triangle have?",
    answers: [3, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate through your questions array as well.
the first question is in:

```
questions[0].question
```

Btw:
your questions variable should be an array. (like your answers)
try the following:

```
    let questions =
  [{
    question: "How many sides does a square have?",
    answers: [4, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },
  {
    question: "How many sides does a triangle have?",
    answers: [3, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }
;

const iterator = questions.answers.keys();
for (const key of iterator) {
  if (key === questions.correctAnswer) {
    console.log(questions.question + ": " + questions.answers[key]);
  }
}]
```

**Explanation:**

The questions array bundles all your question objects. If you want to ask a specific question you need to tell javascript which question object it is that you want to ask.

Is it the first question?:

```
question[0].question
```

meaning: "How many sides does a square have?"

or maybe another one?

Answer (score 0):

Make your questions as an array of objects and iterate over it's simple as that here:

```
let questions = [
  {
    question: "How many sides does a square have?",
    answers: [4, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },
  {
    question: "How many sides does a triangle have?",
    answers: [3, 6, 8],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }]
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, first of all you could iterate over an array of questions and only then check your answers. But, to my mind, in your repo structure of questions is a bit ambiguous. It's not clear is answers contains set of answers for the quiz (if so why you check this list for correct answer? I mean, this set should contains correct answer anyway, I suppose) or indices of user answers (if so you should check value of index in correctAnswer property against values in answers array).

```
for (const question of questions) {
    if ([check your answers with question.answers and question.correctAnswer]) {
        [output: something like question.answers[question.correctAnswer]]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as already stated above, you need to define your questions in an array.
Like:

```
const questions = [{
    question: "How many sides does a triangle have?",
    answer: [3, 5, 7],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },
  {
    question: "some question?",
    answer: [1, 42, "another answer"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }
]
```

You are probably making it harder than you have to by using .keys(), this array function returns an iterator with the index numbers instead of the actual values, read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys)

Since you are storing the index to the right answer you can easily solve this by looping through your questions array and deal with the answers like this:

```
for (let q of questions) {
  console.log(q.question, ": ", answers[correctAnswer])
}
```

This works since correctAnswer holds the index key for the right answer.